# Is a Subgroup Characteristic in its Normalizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H \subseteq G$. Is it true that $H$ is a characteristic subgroup of $N_{G}(H)$? Knowing that "the something" subgroup must be characteristic, I believe it must be true. 
Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that $H$ is not "the something" subgroup of $N_G(H)$ here...

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It appears to me that the structure of $N_{G}(H)$ is dependent on $H$, so why is it not considered a unique subgroup?

Comment: The question is not whether $N_G(H)$ is dependent on $H$, bu the other way around: whether you can uniquely define $H$ in terms of $N_G(H)$

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G=C_p\times C_p$ and $H$ any subgroup of order $p$. Then $N_G(H)=G$
but $H$ is not characteristic in $G$.

Comment: Nice example! thank you1

Answer (score 3):

The normalizer of any subgroup of an abelian group is the whole group, but there are subgroups of abelian groups that are not characteristic.

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample!

Comment: @Sean No problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a positive answer to the question.

If $H \leq G$ with gcd$(|H|, |G:H|)=1$, then $H$ char $N_G(H)$. (Example are Sylow subgroups!). The statement follows from the fact a normal subgroup having coprime order and index, must be characteristic.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you for the insight! :)

Comment: Sean, you are welcome!